# Variable persisting between function calls

Tags: matlab, scope

Suppose I want to call a function twice, but I need the function to remember variables it initialized the first time it is called so execution can be changed in subsequent calls.

For example if I have a piece of code like this:

```
function random
 if exist('a','var') == 0
   fprintf('hello\n');
   a = 1;
 else 
   disp('goodbye\n');
 end
end
```

How could I get MATLAB to remember that `a` equals 1 when when I call the code again? Specifically, I'm hoping to use this for a push button callback function in a program I'm writing.

Comment: static variable usually isn't a good idea, consider a `class`?

Comment: How would a `class` address this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MATLAB supports the keyword `persistent`, which you would use as follows:

```
function toggleval_persist
    % Set up the persistent variable and initialize it.
    persistent a;
    if isempty(a)
        a = 0;
    end      

    if ( a == 0 ) 
        disp('hello');
        a = 1;
    else
        a = 0; 
        disp('goodbye');
    end
end
```

Also, I wouldn't recommend using a persistent variable for toggling a button state.  The button's state is usually available in the object structure for the GUI if you're using MATLAB's UI system.

Comment: You can also use `setappdata`/`getappdata` to store arbitrary user-defined state on handles, such as on buttons. That would be the way to do it if you wanted to toggle something on a per-widget basis, instead of whether the function had been called by *anything* before.

Answer (score -1):

What you could do (in the optics of using this code in a GUI) is set up a flag telling whether `a` has been initialized or not and pass it as an argument to the function `random`. Storing the flag (let's call it `a_flag`) in the handles structure of the GUI, for instance, would allow you to keep track of its value (actually stored in `handles.a_flag`) for example.

So in other words,you could set the flag to 0 during the creation of the GUI (or in its `Opening_Fcn` if you are using GUIDE) as follows:

```
handles.a_flag = false;
```

and then in the function called `random`, which you could call with: `random(handles.a_flag)`:

```
function random(a_flag)

 if ~a_flag

    %// Update the flag
    a_flag = true;

    fprintf('hello\n');
    a = 1;
 else 
   fprintf('goodbye\n');
 end

end
```

Even simpler would be to use global variables...but I like that idea better :)

**EDIT**

The point of my code is to demonstrate that we can use the handles structure of a GUI (as asked by the OP) to store the value of the flag. Since the structure is accessible from every callback pressing the pushbutton will update it the same way a persistent variable would.

Please try this code to see what I mean:

```
function TestGUI

clear
clc

hFigure = figure('Position',[200 200 200 150]);

handles.Disp_a_title = uicontrol('Style','text','String','a','Position',[20 100 60 20]);
handles.Disp_aflag = uicontrol('Style','text','String','0','Position',[100 100 60 20]);

handles.Button = uicontrol('Style','Push','Position',[50 50 60 20],'String','Update a','Callback',@(s,e) PushCb);

a = 0;
handles.a_flag = false;

guidata(hFigure,handles)

    function PushCb(~,~)


        handles = guidata(hFigure);

        fprintf('Flag is %i\n',handles.a_flag)


        if handles.a_flag == false;

            disp('hello\n');

            a = 1;
            handles.a_flag = true;

        else
            disp('goodbye\n');
        end

        guidata(hFigure,handles)
    end
end
```

Pressing the button twice results in the following output in the Command Window:

```
Flag is 0
hello\n
Flag is 1
goodbye\n
```

Which from what I understood is the expected behaviour the OP is looking for.

Comment: Matlab variables are pass-by-value. How would `a_flag = true` update the flag state in the caller's context?

Comment: Please see my edit @AndrewJanke. What I meant to say is that the flag would be stored in the handles structure of the GUI, hence it would be accessible in the callback to keep track of whether the function was called. As I re-read my answer that was not clear at all though.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense now.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewJanke. Everything was clear in my mind but I failed to explain it properly haha.